# Reverse number array multiline textboxes

Tags: vb.net

basically, I want to reverse the numbers. (in the textbox there will be only 2-digit numbers)

if I have Textbox1.text:

```
12
2
41
71
70
```

I want to display in the box (Textbox1.text)

```
21
2
14
17
70
```

Function:

```
Public Shared Function Reverse(num As Integer) As Integer
        Dim _reverse As Integer = 0
        While num <> 0
            _reverse *= 10
            _reverse += num Mod 10
            num \= 10
        End While
        Return _reverse
    End Function
```

it should work, it actually works, but I don't know how to arrange it to work in all lines.

```
    For Each lines In TextBox1.Lines
    Dim rev = Reverse(lines)
    lines.Replace(lines, rev)
    Next
```

Comment: You need to loop through all lines of TextBox1. That's all!

Comment: Done :( :( :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect example of what happens when people try to write code without knowing what the code is supposed to. What the code is supposed to do is not just the end result but the steps to get there. If you don't know what the steps are then you shouldn't be writing any code because it's unlikely that what you write will do anything useful. Code is simply an implementation of logic so you should be getting the logic down first. It doesn't take any programming experience to work out the logic because we could all do this if it was a manual process and that would be the same logic.

So, what are the steps involved?

1. Get the lines of the text.
2. Loop over the lines.
3. Reverse the current line.
4. Replace the original line with the result of reversing.
5. Replace the text with the complete results.

If you actually consider each of those steps, it should be obvious that you cannot use a `For Each` loop because that will only let you get data out of a list, not put data into it. That would make it obvious that a `For` loop is the right choice, because will let you get data out and put it in. Now you can write code that actually does something useful.

```vb
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines

For i = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim line = lines(i)
    Dim number = CInt(line)
    Dim result = Reverse(number)

    lines(i) = result.ToString()
Next

TextBox1.Lines = lines
```

Simple stuff but, again, if you don't know what the code has to actually do, writing code to do it is a challenge. Always break the problem down into smaller parts first, so you can work on each part individually, and always work out the logic you're trying to implement - and test that logic manually - before trying to write code to implement it.